# IntelliJ Data Source - possible to switch the "Driver" without recreating it?

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea, driver, datasource

I am using IntelliJ, I have the `Database` view available and I click the "spanner" icon to configure `Data Sources and Drivers` via the dialog box.

On the left under *Global Data Sources* I have a Data Source set up: `SQL Server - my_db@server123`

When I configured it I choce the Driver: `SQL Server (jTds)` but now I want to change the Driver to `SQL Server (Microsoft)`.

... how can I change the driver for an already configured Data Source in IntelliJ?

Clicking on the link next to `Driver` : *SQL Server (jTds)* jumps to the driver configuration and doesn't allow me to change it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Goto the datasource and right click on the datasource -->>properties

   [image: picture 1]
2. Then right click on the datasource->change driver

   [image: picture 2]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)